# Accessibility Check fail when using TextInputLayout

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm using the new TextInputLayout provided by Android.support to do floating label. But it will fail Espresso Accessibility Check because "View is missing speakable text needed for a screen reader".

Looked into it and find out the TextInputLayout will nullify hint when parent does addView(). This is basically how it can float the label up(set the label, nullify the hint). And any EditText with null hint will fail the accessibility check.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue? It's really driving me crazy..

Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints aren't great for accessibility in general.  They disappear when text is entered.  Try using a "LabelFor" instead.  If you don't want a visible label, you can set your label to not be displayed.

This app will give you hints on how to make text boxes accessible.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dequesystems.accessibility101

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: https://www.deque.com/blog/accessible-text-input-android/

Answer (score 10):

A great way to make TextInputLayout accessible is to use "LabelFor" as recommanded by ChrisCM, but you don't have to add an invisible label view to do so: **Just put the `labelFor` or your `Textinputlayout` and make it point to your `EditText`**

**Example**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:labelFor="@+id/username"
  android:contentDescription="@string/username_hint"
  android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite">
    <edittext
      android:id="@+id/username"
      android:hint="@string/username_hint"
       …/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**This way you get the exact same visual behaviour and make "Espresso Accessibility Check" and Talkback happy :)**

*(To make TextInputLayout fully accessible I also added `android:accessibilityliveregion` on the TextInputLayout element to trigger talkback whenever the error is poping*)

A big thanks to this post [this blog post](http://www.last-child.com/accessible-android-inputs-with-material-design/) which helped a lot

---

Comment: Now it show error `Unknown attribute android:labelfor` and `Unknown attribute android:contentdescription` and aapt2 check will fail when building the project

Comment: @HendraWD You need to fix the upper/lowercase in the attributes. I also fixed it in the answer above

Comment: I added this but TalkBack does not read the `contentDescription` from the TextInputLayout. It only reads out the `hint` from the EditText. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if this is a false positive you can ignore checks as described  [here](https://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/testing#espresso)

```
val validator: AccessibilityValidator = AccessibilityChecks.enable().apply {
setSuppressingResultMatcher(
        allOf(
                matchesCheckNames(`is`("TouchTargetSizeViewCheck")),
                matchesViews(withId(R.id.my_overflow))
        )
)}
```

The following rules are invoked when we enable tests for accessibility checks:

- TouchTargetSizeViewCheck Target height or target width less than 48
  dp is flagged, unless there is a touchdelegate detected.
- TextContrastViewCheck Checks text color and background and factors in
  large text, and calculates the contrast ratio: - 4.5 for regular
  text, 3 for large text.
- DuplicateSpeakableTextViewHierarchyCheck If
  two Views in a hierarchy have the same speakable text, that could be
  confusing for users if at least one of them is clickable.
- SpeakableTextPresentViewCheck If the view is focusable, this checks
  whether valid speakable text exists, and errors if the view is
  missing speakable text needed for a screen reader.
- EditableContentDescViewCheck Throws an error if Editable TextView has
  a contentDescription.
- ClickableSpanViewCheck Checks if ClickableSpan
  is inaccessible. Individual spans cannot be selected independently in
  a single TextView, and accessibility services are unable to call
  ClickableSpan#onClick.
- RedundantContentDescViewCheck Accessibility
  services are aware of the view's type and can use that information as
  needed. For example, it throws a warning if the content description
  has a redundant word, such as “button.”
- DuplicateClickableBoundsViewCheck Throws an error if Clickable view
  has the same bounds as another clickable view (likely a descendent).
  Sometimes there are containers marked clickable, and they don't
  process any click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a TextView that has

```
android:text="My Announcement For Edit Text"
android:labelFor="@id/my_edit_text".
```

`Visibility = gone` and `visibility = invisible` will make it so this label is not announced.  Also if you set height and width to 0dp, this will not announce.  Instead, constrain the view to be off the screen using something like:

`app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"`

So your textview will look like this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:labelFor="@+id/my_edit_text"
        android:text="Label For My Edit Text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using `withClassName` for a view

```
AccessibilityChecks.enable().setSuppressingResultMatcher(
        AccessibilityCheckResultUtils.matchesViews(
            Matchers.anyOf(
                ViewMatchers.withResourceName("textview1"),
                ViewMatchers.withResourceName("button1"),
                ViewMatchers.withClassName(Matchers.endsWith("TextInputLayout"))
            )
        )
    )
```