# Accessibility Checks - TextInputEditText has contradictory exceptions

Tags: android, android-espresso, accessibility

All, we're using the Espresso Accessibility Checking and are getting the following errors for the same view. What's the best way to fix this? Removing the content description fixes the second error but the first still remains. Is there a way to satisfy the Accessibility Checker for TextInputEditText?

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/accessibility-checking

```
AccessibilityViewCheckException: There were 2 accessibility errors:
TextInputEditText{id=2131362592, res-name=reason}: View is missing speakable text needed for a screen reader
TextInputEditText{id=2131362592, res-name=reason}: Editable TextView should not have a contentDescription.
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that this error will go away if you set the hint in the TextInputEditText and remove the labelFor in TextInputLayout.

According to Google documentation, setting the hint is the way to tell Accessibility about your view for EditTexts.

> When labeling editable elements, such as EditText objects, use the android:hint XML attribute for static elements and the setHint() method for dynamic elements to indicate each element's purpose. ([Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps))

Also, in Google's example of TextInputLayout, it does not specify that you need to have the labelFor field. ([Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout))

Code Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I am aware that this post is in direct contradiction to this post:
[Accessibility Check fail when using TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770009/accessibility-check-fail-when-using-textinputlayout). However, doing the things mentioned in that post did not work for me on the latest version of Android.

Comment: I had a similar problem because I was using `labelFor` in the `TextView` referencing an `EditText`. Removing `labelFor` and using `hint` in the `EditText` did the trick